# Vaadin 10+: Which jars does tomcat have to scan?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10

To speed up tomcat startup, I usually configure (dramatic effect):

```
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=*.jar
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan=myapp.jar
```

But skipping everything breaks Vaadin 11. I tried

```
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan=myapp.jar,vaadin*.jar
```

Which jars do I have to scan so that Vaadin 11 can work / startup correctly?

Comment: have you tried with `flow-server-*.jar`?

Comment: @cfrick Yes thank you! That seems to work. Feel free to convert to an answer. Currently I am using `jarsToSkip=*.jar` and `jarsToScan=myapp.jar,vaadin*.jar,flow*.jar`

Comment: That is the answer you have deleted.  Why not undelete it? And is `flow-server` alone not enough?

Comment: @cfrick I deleted my answer because after some testing I initially thought that it didn't work after all (still not 100% convinced). And in addition it would have allowed me to show my appreciation for your looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=*.jar
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan=myapp.jar,vaadin*.jar,flow*.jar,polymer*.jar,iron*.jar,shady*.jar
```

Seems to work so far, although I am a bit uneasy about possible other things that might be needed. e.g. polymer*.jar. So now when I run into weird problems, first thing I do is change it back to scan everything, to rule out that possible cause.

Edit: Already had to adjust the list.